# How can I use Theil-Sen method with geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to implement a theil-sen operator in ggplot's geom_smooth. In an ideal world it would read something like: `geom_smooth(..., methods= "mblm")`.  I cannot seem to find an answer to this, nor can I figure out how I would customize the methods for this.  Any advice, pointers, or code help would be greatly appreciated.

I would like to effectively replacing add "mblm" to the methods options in geom_smooth:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mblm)


# Option 1 - adding 'mblm' into the methods directly
ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, wt))+   
geom_point() +     
geom_smooth(method='mblm')

# Option 2 - defining the Theil-Sen function outside
ts_fit <- mblm(qsec ~ wt, data = mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, wt))+   
geom_point() +     
geom_smooth( alpha=0,method=ts_fit)
```

Neither works. I generate the warning `Warning message:
Computation failed in stat_smooth(): unused argument (weights = weight)`, which is essential an error in the geom_smooth line. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Nate

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use as `method` the name of any modeling function that has a formula interface and a `predict` method. It's definitely possible. Do you have a fitting function?

Comment: For example, set `my_lm = "lm"`, and you can then use `geom_smooth(method = "my_lm")` just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Interesting thought. Using that logic doesn't work though.  The updated code would be as follows: `library(tidyverse) 
library(mblm)
ts_fit <- mblm(qsec ~ wt, data = mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, wt))+   
geom_point() +     
geom_smooth( alpha=0,method='ts_fit')`

Comment: In that case ggplot doesn't know what to do with the outputs from `mblm`

Comment: The `method` is the name of the function, not some model object. Try `geom_smooth(method = "mblm")`.

Comment: (Sorry, in my `lm` example above I meant `my_lm = lm`, not `"lm"`). I am getting a warning and no smooth when I try with `mblm`. Maybe instead of a vague general question for pointers and advice, you should edit your question to "How can I use `mblm` with `geom_smooth`, making it nice and specific.

Comment: @Gregor good call.  I wasn't initially looking for specific advise, but it was definitely taking that turn during this conversation.  I have updated the question to be more pointed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured it out.  Here is the answer for completion.

```
# Option 2 - defining the Theil-Sen function outside
ts_fit <- mblm(qsec ~ wt, data = mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, wt))+   
geom_point() +     
  geom_abline(intercept = coef(ts_fit)[1], slope = coef(ts_fit)[2])
```

Update:
Figured out a more repeatable way to accomplish this.

```
sen <- function(..., weights = NULL) {
  mblm::mblm(...)
}

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(qsec, wt)) +   
  geom_point() +     
  geom_smooth(method = sen)
```

Comment: so great that this is posted here!  totally save me hours of coding!